# Resulting beta distribution from two different samples

Tags: sampling, beta-distribution, rare-events

Let’s say each sample consists of 300 units inspected for defects.

I have historic data from 100 samples in the past that give me an idea of what I expect the defect rate to be.

I have a new batch to sample. I pull 300 units at random and inspect. How do I include the historical data from those 100 samples with the single sample from the new batch to get an estimate for the defect rate for the entire new batch?

In my case the detected defect rate is always zero. We have never had a defect in 100 samples. For the new batch if we don’t detect a defect in any of the 300 selected units I can say that we are approximately 95% confident the defect rate is less than 1/100 (-log(.05)/300) in the rest of the batch (assume the population sampled is very large). However this ignores the long history of zero defects and I think overestimates our expectation of defects. I’d like to resolve this.

I’d imagine there might be a way to weigh the historical data differently from the sample taken directly from the batch in question, but how?

Answer (score 1):

Inclusion of prior data is easily done under a Bayesian paradigm, which is quite straightforward to apply using beta distributions (since that is its own conjugate prior). Briefly, you define a prior distribution that reflects your assumptions on defect probability before the experiment, in this case based on the historical data. Together with the data you can derive a posterior distribution, which reflects the updated probability taking into account both historical and current observations.

A beta distribution $B$ in its $\alpha$, $\beta$ parametrization can be thought of as $\alpha$ being the number of successes and $\beta$ the number of failures, with the requirement that $\alpha >0$ and $\beta > 0$. For example, if you want to use your 100 historical observations directly this can be expressed as $B(0.001, 100)$, taking a very small non-zero value for $\alpha$ since it must be > 0 and considering 'success' here as a defect occurring. The resulting distribution already has a lot of mass around probability of defect near zero, there's no use plotting anything above 1%:
[image: Plot of beta(0.001, 100) density]

Incorporating new data and deriving a posterior is as simple as adding the additional successes (defects) to $\alpha$ and the rest to $\beta$. If you were to observe another zero defects in your 300 new observations the resulting posterior will be $B(0.001, 400)$:
[image: Plot of beta(0.001, 400) density]

You can make probability statements directly from this distribution, for example there is a 95% posterior chance that the probability of defect is below $7.5e{-}26$ (in R: `qbeta(.95, .001, 400)`), which I'm sure doesn't suffer from numerical precision issues at all. Consider another example where you'd have observed 50 defects and 250 non-defects, your posterior would be $B(50.001, 350)$ and the 95% upper credible limit for defect probability approximately $0.153$.

An elegant thing about these beta distributions is that they carry an effective sample size of $\alpha+\beta$, so if you want to assign less weight to your prior you can simply reduce these parameters proportionally.